# How to compare Char Strings

Tags: python, string

So I'm trying to find the least/smallest char in a string. The program is suppose to compare each character to each other and finds the smallest char. Should look like this when calling.

```
least("rcDefxB")
The least char is B
```

this is the code that i have so far

```
def least(inputS):
for i in range(len(inputS)-1):
    current = inputS[i]
    nextt = inputS[i+1]
    if current > nextt:
        current = nextt
        nextt = inputS[i+2]
        print('The least char is',current)
```

but the output that i get is this:

```
least("rcDefxB")
C
D
IndexError: string index out of range
in line least nextt = inputS[i+2]
```

I probably incremented the wrong way or compared my characters the wrong way. I feel like i have the right setup, let me know where i missed up in my code.

Comment: Push everything below `def leastChar(inputString)` 4 spaces to the right.

Comment: And of course, change `index < len(inputString)` to `index < len(inputString)-1`.

Comment: by smallest do you mean the ASCII position or the alphabet position(ignore upper or lower case)

Comment: And of course, move the `print` statement outside (after) the `while` loop.

Comment: And of course, no need to condition the `print` statement (since you want it to take place always).

Comment: by smallest i mean ASCII position

Comment: you are reinventing the wheel - use `min`

Comment: I know using min is much easier but i'm being asked to write it on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use :

```
min("rcDefxB")
```

If you really want to write it on your own, you could use :

```
def leastChar(inputString):
  min_char = inputString[0]
  for char in inputString:
    if char < min_char:
      min_char = char
  print 'The leastchar is %s' % min_char
```

Both methods require a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Duminil solution is better, but if you want your code works properly you should modify it as follows:

```
inputString = "rcDefxB"
index = 0
while index < len(inputString) - 1:
    currentChar = inputString[index]
    nextChar = inputString[index + 1]
    if currentChar > nextChar:
        currentChar = nextChar
    index += 1
print('The leastchar is',currentChar)
```

Answer (score 2):

if by smallest you mean the ASCII code position just:

```
>>> s = "aBCdefg"
>>> min(s)
'B'
```

but if you mean the alphabet position ignore the upper or lower case:

```
>>> min(s, key=lambda x: x.upper())
'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following approach:

```
def least(inputString):
    leastChar = min(list(inputString))
    print('The leastchar is', leastChar)
```

After running `least("rcDefxB")`, you'll have:

```
The leastchar is B
```